# Camera on M1 MacBook Pro can't be found after waking from sleep -- until another app uses it

Tags: google-chrome, sleep, macbook-pro, camera, macos-bigsur

When I:

1. use Google Chrome for video conferencing (e.g. Google Meet, Focusmate, other sites)
2. then put my M1 MacBook Pro to sleep by closing the lid for five seconds
3. then open it again

...the camera cannot be found by Chrome. (Even though Chrome reports that camera permissions are allowed). Reloading the page does not resolve the issue. If I force quit Chrome and restart it, then it finds the camera fine. This is consistently repeatable.

Here's what's weird: if I instead do this:

1. use Google Chrome for video conferencing (e.g. Google Meet, Focusmate, other sites)
2. then put my M1 MacBook Pro to sleep by closing the lid for five seconds
3. then open it again
4. then open Firefox and have Firefox use the camera on a video conferencing site

...that somehow makes Chrome suddenly find the camera! Without having to restart Chrome, it starts using the camera with no problem. These steps are totally repeatable for me.

You might be tempted to think that this is a Google Chrome issue, but clearly the operating system is doing something to make the resources become available to chrome, which it could have done all along. FWIW, I have turned off all Chrome extensions. It also works to just leave Firefox open in the background on a site that uses the camera -- then Chrome is never unable to find the camera!

Versions:

- Using Chrome version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (arm64) [latest build as of 2021-05-22]
- Using MacOS Big Sur 11.3.1 [latest build as of 2021-05-22] on an M1 MacBook Pro 13"; 330GB storage available
- Using Firefox version 88.0.1 (64-bit) [latest build as of 2021-05-22]

Comment: If other browsers don't have this problem, then Chrome probably has a bug in its resume-after-wake code. Have you tried testing a Chromium nightly to see if it's already been fixed?

Comment: Good idea, but I get the same exact behavior with updated Canary, version 92.0.4515.9 (Official Build) canary (arm64)